# How to save the data from dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-dialog

I have an accordion where  the link of dialog box present, but when the dialog box open it didn't save the field and not redirecting, what's the issue? i tried a lot to figure out but didn't get any success.

This is my view :

```
<?php v_start($d);?>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var icons = {
            header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
            activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
        };
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            icons: icons
        });
        $( "#toggle" ).button().click(function() {
            if ( $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons" ) ) {
                 $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", null );
            } else {
                 $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", icons );
            }
        });
    }); 
    $(function()
    {
        var $dialog = $("#view_dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Add Group',
            height: 200,
            width: 1200,
            resizable: true,
            modal: true,
            buttons:
            {
                "Ok": function()
                {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    $(".view_dialog").click(function()
    {
        $dialog.load($(this).attr('href'), function ()
        {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
    <div class="inner-heading"> 
        <div class="inner-heading-left">
        <h1><?php echo __l('Manage Groups');?></h1>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div id="accordion">
        <div>
            <h3 style="margin-right: 0PX; margin-left: 30px; font-size:20px;"><?php echo __l('User Define Group') ?></h3>
        </div>
    <div class="firsttable">        
        <div class="top-button">
            //dialog link
            <?php echo $this->Manager->hlink('Add Group', array('action' => 'add_define_group'), array('class' => 'view_dialog')); ?>           
            <?php echo $this->Manager->link('Add Group',array('action'=>'add_define_group')) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 style="margin-right: 0PX; margin-left: 30px; font-size:20px;"><?php echo __l('Mailing Group') ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="firsttable">        
        <div class="top-button">
            <?php echo $this->Manager->link('Add Group',array('contoller'=>'ContactGroups','action'=>'add_define_group','mailing')) ?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 style="margin-right: 0PX; margin-left: 30px; font-size:20px;"><?php echo __l('Dynamic Group') ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="firsttable">
        <div class="top-button">
            <?php echo $this->Manager->link('Add Group',array('contoller'=>'ContactGroups','action'=>'add_define_dynamic_group')) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="view_dialog"></div>
</div>
<?php v_end();?>
```

Bascially i trying to open the dialog box in the accordion , dialogbox will save the data and redirect it, but it didn't save any data and didn't redirect, what can i do with that? 
Any body's help will be appreciated, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Reduce your code to the minimum and let us know what have you tried and where do you think it fails.

Comment: @Steve i have reduced the code

Comment: You seem to be using a 'get' request to perform a 'add' in your database, or am I mistaken? Usually, CakePHP is looking for 'posted' form data to insert/update data. Not sure this is related though, because I don't know how your controller handles this

Comment: Show us the cake code. Most likely you aren't making it past if($this->request->is('post')